# Sine curves that are not equal on both sides?

Tags: trigonometry

I believe this graph (the bottom one) http://cdn.iopscience.com/images/2041-8205/783/1/L15/Full/apjl491264f4_lr.jpg has a sine function, and most likely one that combines two together.

Does anyone happen to know the name for curves like this? Or where I could find the function for it?

Thanks a billion :)

Comment: What you have is definitely not a $sin$ variant. Take a look at:http://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/curves1.htm

Comment: See [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

Answer (score 0):

Every oscillating curve is not sine/harmonic. i.e., not always like $ y^{''}+ y =0.$

It is difficult to guess ( for me) the ODE that results in such a curve. You have to look to the current/voltage balance at a node or junction in a network, and set it up from its constituents.

One case I know leading to elliptic integrals:

$$ \frac{y y^{''}}{ 1+ y^{'2}} + \dfrac {y^2 - \alpha ^2} {y^2 - \beta ^2} =0  $$

They are more pointed near x-axis and broader at points farthest away from it.